# Exclude colors from Material UI theme

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

Is it possible to exclude some color types from MUI palette (MUI v5)? Let's say, I want to exclude background and error colors, and I want to be able to use only colors declared in my custom theme file.

I tried with `never` but it doesn't solve my problem

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    primary: Palette['primary'];
    secondary: Palette['primary'];
    background: never;
    error: never;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to exclude these colors? What happens if you just don't declare them? Or set to undefined?

Comment: I don't want my teammates to use colors not described in our custom palette file. Only colors from our design system should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Would overriding the default Palette like this be a solution ?

```
interface CustomPalette extends Palette {
  background?: never;
  error?: never;
}
```

Of course you need to set this interface to your components or it will still use MUI default palette

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is the **opposite** of [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), however, I'm not sure if it is possible to do in the current stage of TypeScript.

What you can do instead is to overwrite MUI types with unwanted props omitted.

In this case, remove the `palette` and then re-add it with unwanted properties omitted from it. An example of that would be:

```
import { useTheme as useMuiTheme, Theme as MuiTheme } from "@mui/material";

interface Theme extends Omit<MuiTheme, "palette"> {
    palette: Omit<MuiTheme["palette"], "primary">;
}

const useTheme = () => {
    const theme = useMuiTheme();
    return theme as Theme;
};

export default useTheme;
```

And then use your own version of `useTheme` throughout the codebase.